# Why does the first sql query run much faster than the second?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have two queries, one runs very quickly (about 1 sec) the other takes about 8 sec to execute. The only difference is that I create sql variables to hold start and end dates in the slow query, whereas in the fast query the start and end dates are converted on the fly.

I would use the fast query in the excel report but the date values change daily as the report is run on a daily basis, so they would need to be parameterised, hence the need for the second query. I am after an explanation of why the two queries have such different execution times.

Both queries bring back the same number of rows. There is a non clustered index on the Channel and Date_Date columns and a clustered index on the ID column on the table. Thankyou in advance for any help offered.

SLOW QUERY ( 8 sec)

```
declare @startdateStr varchar(8)
declare @enddateStr varchar(8)

select @startdateStr = '20190824'
select @enddateStr = '20190830'

SELECT Date_YYYYMMDD, -- varchar(50) date in YYYYMMDD format 
    Date_Date, -- datetime
    Week_Number, -- int
    Sum(intcol1) AS SumOfIntCol1,
    Sum(intcol2) AS SumOfIntCol2,
    Business_Area
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE [Channel]='ChannelName'
AND convert(date, Date_Date) Between convert(date, @startdateStr)
    And convert(date, @enddateStr)
GROUP BY Date_Date,
    Date_YYYYMMDD,
    Week_Number,
    Business_Area
ORDER BY Date_YYYYMMDD;
```

Fast QUERY (1 sec)

```
SELECT Date_YYYYMMDD, -- varchar(50) date in YYYYMMDD format 
    Date_Date, -- datetime
    Week_Number, -- int
    Sum(intcol1) AS SumOfIntCol1,
    Sum(intcol2) AS SumOfIntCol2,
    Business_Area
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE [Channel]='ChannelName'
AND convert(date, Date_Date) Between convert(date, '20190824') 
    And convert(date, '20190830')
GROUP BY Date_Date,
    Date_YYYYMMDD,
    Week_Number,
    Business_Area
ORDER BY Date_YYYYMMDD;
```

I was expecting the first query to be at least as quick as the second, but it takes 8 sec to execute compared to 1 sec for the second

These are the execution plans, the slow query is on top

[image]

Comment: Are you using [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) ? If you are then you should add the tag indicating this, since in my opinion your question concerns _SQL Server_ and not SQL.

Comment: Can you share with us the execution plans? You can use [Pastetheplan/](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) or [SQL Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) from SentryOne, generate the actual execution plan from that and upload it (through the click of a button from Plan Explorer) to SQLPerformance.

Comment: Why are you using `varchar(8)` for the dates instead of `date`? And what does `Date_YYYYMMDD` contain? Dates have no format, they are binary values. If `Date_YYYYMMDD` is a string field, you have a serious bug

Comment: Instead of converting dates in the AND clause, declaring the variables as dates and avoid all the converts may save some time.

Comment: As for the *second* query being faster, it's probably because the data is already cached in memory.

Comment: You can add 

    option (RECOMPILE)
in the end of your first query and compare results;

Comment: Panagiotis there is a Datetime column as well. I didn't design the table, I just have to work with it.

Comment: Belen nope, it also takes 8 sec with pre-converted date variables as well.

Comment: Panagiotis if I run query 2 first, then query 1, query 1 will still take 8 sec

Comment: Just my 2 cents: SQL Server will create a different plans for the two queries. And, most likely, it'll create two different plans for the _fast_ query if you make the date range bigger (e.g. for a narrower range it'll use an index on dates, for wider range it will use an index on channel). This is normal behavior with variables.

Comment: @JulioM maybe the order of the group by columns is causing this, as it will generate a different execution plan.

Comment: @JulioM in the first query the group order is `Date_Date, Date_YYYYMMDD ..` and the second query `Date_YYYYMMDD,
    Date_Date,`

Comment: Dawood yes you are right, I have amended the queries, but it does not affect the execution times of either. They are different because I was playing around with the orders, group bys etc to find an explanation myself before I posted the question. Thanks

Comment: What is the IO Statistics output for both queries? you can turn that on by `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` - also better to post the XML of the execution plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ - Right click execution plan and `Show Plan XML`

Comment: @SalmanA you're right, it does create two different execution plans. Not sure why though.

Comment: Re execution plans: I don't want to post confidential business stuff up here thanks.

Comment: You can use Date_YYYYMMDD directly for the BETWEEN clause and avoid the type conversion. (I don't know the answer to your question)

Comment: @Javier yes I can, and then it takes even longer!

Comment: @JulioM, yeah could be. Just a thought. :)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/why-does-sql-server-use-a-better-execution-plan-when-i-inline-the-variable - looks like you may need to convert to a stored procedure...

Comment: @NevilleKuyt That looks like the best solution. Thanks